# "Ti voglio tanto tanto bene": multiple usage of "tanto"

Tags: word-usage

Is it adding "tanto" twice the correct way to emphasise the "so much" in this sentence? i.e, so so much:

> Ti voglio tanto tanto bene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but to me it sounds rather childish.

I would say: "Ti voglio **tantissimo** bene". 
*Tantissimo* is the superlative form of the adjective (in Italian we say *superlativo assoluto*). The superlatives are usually formed by eliminating the suffix, in this case -o, and adding -issimo/-issima/-issimi/-issime. As you can see, this is still an adjective and must be inflected according to the word it is referred to. "Bene" is gender masculine so the -o at the end of "tantissimo" should be used.

You can also say: "Ti voglio **davvero** bene"
o "Ti voglio **un sacco di** bene" (informal).

Comment: I wouldn't define it childish, I'd call it very informal, only suitable for an intimate exchange between lovers or very good friends.

Comment: Actually, *bene* in *volere bene* is a fixed use of the noun [*bene*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bene2). So we may have the doubt whether *tanto* is here an adverb (as in *amare tanto*) or an adjective that agrees with bene. I am inclined towards the latter, thinking, say, about *avere tant**a** fame*. In this case, however, *bene* is masculine, not neuter.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, "tanto tanto bene" could be used both in a childish context (for example, mum-child) or intimate, though in this case it sounds a little old-fashioned to my ears. I'd add that in a teen conversation "ti voglio TROPPO bene" could be used - I personally hate it, but it's rather commonplace, especially when texting.

Answer (score 2):

During my primary school, I was taught that “superlativo assoluto” can be made in several ways

- with the adjectival suffix *-issimo*: *ti voglio tantissimo bene*;
- with *tanto*, *molto*, *estremamente* or similar adverb: not for this case, obviously; for instance *la casa è molto alta*;
- with reduplication: *ti voglio tanto tanto bene*.

The sentence *ti voglio tanto tanto bene* sounds rather intimate (child/parent, lovers), but reduplication can be seen also in other contexts:

> Era il segnale: Renzo lo sentì, fece coraggio a Lucia, con una stretta di braccio; e tutt'e due, in punta di piedi, vennero avanti, rasentando il muro, zitti zitti; arrivarono all'uscio, lo spinsero adagino adagino; cheti e chinati, entraron nell'andito, dov'erano i due fratelli ad aspettarli. Renzo accostò di nuovo l'uscio pian piano; e tutt'e quattro su per le scale, non facendo rumore neppur per uno.

From “I promessi sposi”, chapter VIII: the night of the deceits.

A superlative *zittissimo* of *zitto* would be cumbersome, but *zitto zitto* conveys the idea of somebody who is silent at the highest possible degree.

Comment: May you add to your answer that this excerpt comes from *I promessi sposi* by Manzoni?

Comment: @Charo Isn't it obvious? 